# Python for statement | MIT OCW

Tags: python

Can anyone help to understand why is this not working?

What is wrong with this procedure, which is supposed to return True if
the element x occurs in the list items, and False otherwise?

```
def member (x, items):
    for i in items:
        if x == i:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: For *each* element in the list  you `return` either `True` or `False`. Meaning, even for the very first element in the list, the function will `return True` or `False`. And then stop.

Comment: Also… `return x in items` is the much more practical code…

Comment: Don't forget `in`; `l = [1, 2, 3]; 2 in l;`

Answer (score 0):

because your function returns true or false if the 1st element equals x...

easiest solution is:

```
def member (x, items):
    return x in items
```

and this is a solution based on your code:

```
def member (x, items):
    for i in items:
        if x == i:
            return True
    return False
```